# UI of my app gets broken when testing on a phone [Android]

Tags: android

I am trying to do some simple app to practice, and the user interface gets broken for some reason I don't know why when I run test on my phone. I did an app on android only once before and I didn't have this problem, I was using a different phone though. I'm testing this on Samsung Galaxy A5.

That's how it looks in project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFIU7.jpg

And that's how it looks on my phone: [http://imgur.com/a/uki84](https://imgur.com/a/uki84)

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Show layout file

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d9b4b678798d74952d50b7b2618ea3e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your views have locations set with the tools:... attribute. The locations set this way (using tools:) position the views within the Android Studio editor, and Android Studio editor only. It doesn't do anything at all to position the views for when the app is actually run, that's why all your views are on top of each other, they simply don't have any attributes to indicate their positioning on the screen when the app is run.

You should check tutorials for how to use ConstraintLayout (if you want to use that layout) which is a recent (2016) addition to Android and position your views with the constraints you need. Or you could use some of the older layouts like LinearLayout which should be perfectly fine for your layout needs.

And absolute positioning of the views like you have with the use of the tools:... attribute is also a big no most of the time. Views need to be positioned in some relative way within a layout, which doesn't mean it has to be within a RelativeLayout :), just saying that the views should be positioned in reference to the layout containing them, not just at some absolute point f.e. (150, 110).

Comment: Thanks for an advice, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple layout. You can use `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`.

**Here is an example using `LinearLayout`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Login"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hasło"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Loguj"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Nie masz jeszcze konta? Kliknij tutaj."
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Woah it fixed it for me, thanks a lot! Was just using a constraint layout instead of linear a problem?

Comment: My pleasure...If my solution works, please accept my answer and vote it up. Thanks in advance.